# How can I setup WIX installer to check the version of a database before installing?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, conditional-statements

I have a database that is created by the WIX installer using SqlScript and SqlString tags.  Inside the database is a table "AppVersion" with a field "VersionNumber".

I can create the database just fine, but I'm working on the upgrade script now.  How can I make my upgrade MSI check the value of the AppVersion.VersionNumber field as a condition of upgrading?

I see tags to check registry values, but nothing so far on how to check database values as a condition.

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT* Oh yeah, saving the value in the registry is not viable because the databases are backed up / restored to different machines often enough that the installer itself must use the database version field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I put all of that logic into SQL.  A script should be smart enough to create a table only if it doesn't already exist and to alter a table only if it needs to.  It's not the job of the installer to do all that logic and then decide which SQL scripts to run.